# Появляется listing directory / когда запускаю сайт

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Хочется как-то исправить это.
Когда на vs code с помощью *live server* я запускаю сайт появляется сайт с названием *listing directory /*, там же изображены все папки и файлы (можно понажимать на них, а при клике на html файл сайт открывается)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы этого не происходило, вам нужно иметь файл `index.html` в корне проекта. Тогда будет открываться именно он.

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: Если ответ был полезен - нажмите стрелочку вверх и если решает ваш вопрос - галочку.